# My .NET windows app, running on Azure VM Windows server, not receiving email from Internet

Tags: windows, email, azure, smtp

I send a text message to the email address of my Azure VM Windows server.
My domain name service (Network Solutions) routes the email to my server.
At my server, Wireshark shows this incoming email and the destination email address, and my iphone's phone number that sent the text.

But, this email never gets to the expected destination of C:\inetpub\mailroot\Drop\ on the Azure VM.

This worked last year until November when I shutdown the VM for a few months, to save money while not in use.
In 2017, I restarted VM ok.  I can log to it and run Wireshark.

I've verified at the server that its SMTP service is running.

Here is Wireshark port-25 (SMTP) activity...

```
   Frame 10: 121 bytes on wire (968 bits), 121 bytes captured (968 bits) on interface 0
Ethernet II, Src: Microsof_31:b0:26 (00:0d:3a:31:b0:26), Dst: Cisco_85:10:3c (74:26:ac:85:10:3c)
    Destination: Cisco_85:10:3c (74:26:ac:85:10:3c)
        Address: Cisco_85:10:3c (74:26:ac:85:10:3c)
        .... ..0. .... .... .... .... = LG bit: Globally unique address (factory default)
        .... ...0 .... .... .... .... = IG bit: Individual address (unicast)
    Source: Microsof_31:b0:26 (00:0d:3a:31:b0:26)
        Address: Microsof_31:b0:26 (00:0d:3a:31:b0:26)
        .... ..0. .... .... .... .... = LG bit: Globally unique address (factory default)
        .... ...0 .... .... .... .... = IG bit: Individual address (unicast)
    Type: IPv4 (0x0800)
Internet Protocol Version 4, Src: 100.112.150.65, Dst: 98.137.12.182
    0100 .... = Version: 4
    .... 0101 = Header Length: 20 bytes (5)
    Differentiated Services Field: 0x00 (DSCP: CS0, ECN: Not-ECT)
    Total Length: 107
    Identification: 0x30df (12511)
    Flags: 0x02 (Don't Fragment)
    Fragment offset: 0
    Time to live: 128
    Protocol: TCP (6)
    Header checksum: 0x0000 [validation disabled]
    [Header checksum status: Unverified]
    Source: 100.112.150.65
    Destination: 98.137.12.182
    [Source GeoIP: Unknown]
    [Destination GeoIP: Unknown]
Transmission Control Protocol, Src Port: 25, Dst Port: 46076, Seq: 343, Ack: 108, Len: 55
    Source Port: 25
    Destination Port: 46076
    [Stream index: 0]
    [TCP Segment Len: 55]
    Sequence number: 343    (relative sequence number)
    [Next sequence number: 398    (relative sequence number)]
    Acknowledgment number: 108    (relative ack number)
    Header Length: 32 bytes
    Flags: 0x018 (PSH, ACK)
    Window size value: 514
    [Calculated window size: 131584]
    [Window size scaling factor: 256]
    Checksum: 0x6a4e [unverified]
    [Checksum Status: Unverified]
    Urgent pointer: 0
    Options: (12 bytes), No-Operation (NOP), No-Operation (NOP), Timestamps
    [SEQ/ACK analysis]
Simple Mail Transfer Protocol
    Response: 550 5.7.1 Unable to relay for pray@prayershepherd.com\r\n
        Response code: Requested action not taken: mailbox unavailable (550)
        Response parameter: 5.7.1 Unable to relay for pray@prayershepherd.com
```

Comment: So, it's not this? `Response: 550 5.7.1 Unable to relay for pray@prayershepherd.com\r\n
        Response code: Requested action not taken: mailbox unavailable (550)`

Answer (score 0):

I debugged and fixed it.  Problem was somehow my DNS provider changed extension of my URL from .org to .com
Solution was simply, at my server  > IIS6 > SMTP Virtual ..  >  Domains  >  Domain Name:  Add the new .com domain.